# Spring boot: Can't get attributes utf-8 encoding from application.properties file (Output is ÐÒ¯ÑÑÐ³Ò¯Ò¯Ð»ÑÑÐ½)

Tags: java, spring

I have tried a lot of approaches but no success

e.g. I tried setting

```
file.encoding=utf-8,
System.getProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8") , 
spring.banner.charset=utf-8 , 
info.app.encoding=UTF-8 , 
spring.info.git.encoding=UTF-8 , 
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47389354/5525384).

Answer (score 1):

Java properties files are in ISO-8859-1. You can only read them with another character set using `Properties.load(Reader reader)` instead of `Properties.load(InputStream inStream)`. However, as most tools (and I think Spring does to), use `Properties.load(InputStream inStream)` you have no choice but to stick to ISO-8859-1.

If you want to use characters outside of ISO-8859-1 in a properties file, you need to use unicode escapes.