# Java .properties file not support Turkish Character Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, utf-8, properties-file

I want to give Turkish character as a value in my .properties file. But outcome not shown well

I put into properties file

```
myvalue=BİLGEHAN

Outcome B?LGEHAN
```

I found some solutions in stackoverflow. But I want to clarify

I tried to add properties file encoding try both of them UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 not working

```
@PropertySource(
    value = {"my.properties"},
    encoding = "UTF-8"
)
```

I set -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 it is not working native2ascii conversion work

Only thing I can do I use native2ascii and convert my value to ascii format and then my message shows well

I want to clarify is there any way to use my special characters in properties file or is this only way to do convert ascii and use it?

[UTF-8 encoding of application.properties attributes in Spring-Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436927/utf-8-encoding-of-application-properties-attributes-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Changing the encoding doesn't help if your file isn't saved as UTF-8. Make sure that your properties file is an actual `UTF-8` file. Also on older java (and Spring) version the properties are expected to be in ISO-8859-1 format (the default and standard for a long time). The `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` should kind of work but that might depend on how you are launching things.

Comment: Hi I use intellij 2021 and spring 2.5 so I try in newer versions

Answer (score 0):

`Default encoding for .properties files` can be changed in intellij with

> File->Settings->Editor->File Encodings

After changing it to UTF-8 .properties files can be saved as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The issue:

- Historically a stupidity happened and the encoding of .properties files was in ISO-8859-1, Latin-1. For Turkish, Latin-3, one would need to encode the special characters as `\uXXXX` (native2ascii).
- Recent java versions now first try to read the .properties files as UTF-8. This really is ideal. And I recommend going with that. Then working with Cyrillic or Arabic resource bundles will be much easier.

For that to work the **editor** too has to use the UTF-8 encoding. Sometimes already java sources are edited in UTF-8, but properties files using ISO-8859-1 because of the java language standard. So check the IDE.
Maybe use Notepad++ or an other encoding aware editor to check for the encoding.

You can use native2ascii both for encoding and decoding specifying your own encoding. Hence a conversion to UTF-8 is simple.