# Spring boot application.properties how to read Japanese or Katakana character

Tags: java, spring-boot, unicode, character-encoding, application.properties

Following is my property inside the spring boot application.properties file

```
agent.managementId=こんにちは
```

When I am trying to read like

```
@Value("${agent.managementId}")
String tempVal;
```

Then I am getting the garbage value  like "ã“ã‚“ã«ã¡ã¯"

how can I read that value as is?

the value inside the application.properties file

```
agent.managementId=こんにちは
```

Note :- if I change the text in ASCII then it is working but I don't want to convert it into ASCII.

Comment: Try to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436927/utf-8-encoding-of-application-properties-attributes-in-spring-boot).

Comment: @Riccardoi yes, I tried but they are also suggesting convert into ASCII

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by **renaming** **application.property** because as per

[Spring Boot default properties encoding change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882191/spring-boot-default-properties-encoding-change)

Apparently, properties loaded by Spring Boot's ConfigFileApplicationListener are encoded in **ISO 8859-1** character encoding, which is by design and according to format specification.

added

```
@PropertySource(value = "file:app.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

and its working fine